the application did not respond discord bot
I am very new to all of this, first time setting up a bot. But my bot doesn't respond to my /ping command. This is the command that I used following a tutorial:
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");

 module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("ping")
    .setDescription("Replies with Pong!"),
  async execute(interaction) {
    console.log(interaction);
   try {
      await interaction.reply("pong");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error executing ping command: $(error)`);
    }
  },
};

Is there something that's going wrong?

Did you deploy your commands? https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-deployment.html#command-registration
